# Creating an Orchard CMS Custom Document Media Search with filters

Tags: search, lucene, orchardcms

I am trying to create a PDF document media search for Orchard. My media folders contain pdf documents that are ordered into subfolders (in this case my folders are the states of Australia) that I want to be able to filter in the search.

The keyword only searches the document title and a description that is added on upload.. it's not a full-text search of the document contents.

In addition I need to be able to attach a month and date field to each document which can be filtered...

How do I grab the media folder path within the controller and the date fields so that I can create a custom search controller..

Many thanks for any pointers/tips/suggestions... here's an example search form I've created.

---

[image: Search Form]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An old colleague wrote a blog post on custom searches, worth checking out.

http://breakoutdeveloper.com/orchard-cms/creating-an-advanced-search